# is there a defcustom type for a keymap?

Tags: defcustom

I have some defcustom variables that are for keymaps. Is there a way to set the :type in a defcustom to indicate it should be a keymap?

Is the right way to do it like this?

```
:type '(restricted-sexp :match-alternatives keymapp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost right.

`:match-alternatives` needs to be a *list* of predicates:

```lisp
:type '(restricted-sexp :match-alternatives (keymapp))
```

And consider maybe also allowing the value to be a keymap variable (depending on what you really want):

```lisp
:type '(restricted-sexp
        :match-alternatives
        ((lambda (x)
           (or (keymapp x) ; Can be a keymap var.
               (and (symbolp x)
                    (boundp x)
                    (keymapp (symbol-value x)))))))
```